# Bootstrap toggle/switch prevent onChange event in certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap-switch where i want to prevent the onChange trigger to happen in if it not the user who has triggered it.

I use the onChange trigger to run a AJAX script. But when the page is refreshed i change the checkstate based on JSON array. Problem is that when i do this, the onChange event is fired causing the AJAX script to run which i do not want to happen unless it is the user who has issue the onChange. There is a chance that the switch can also change after the page is loaded, by a socket connection to a nodeJs server.

The checkboxes them self look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="clientid_{{$client->id}}" name="toggle" onChange="toggleClient({{$client->id}});">
```

This is the function that is is triggered when the switch is changed:

```
function toggleClient(id)
{
    var toggle = $("#clientid_"+id).is(":checked");
    var url = "/toggleClient";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data :{
            "toggle": toggle,
            "id": id,
        }
    });
}
```

This is what runs when page is loaded

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    //... getting obj.params.clientList herre
    var clientStatusList = JSON.parse(obj.params.clientList); 
    for(client in clientStatusList)
    {
        if(clientStatusList[client].status == true)
        {
            $("#clientid_" + clientStatusList[client].id).prop('checked', true).change();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#clientid_" + clientStatusList[client].id).prop('checked', false).change();
        }
    }
});
```

The above works, but the problem is that when the page is refreshed and every switch get set based on the clientStatusList, the onChange event is triggered and the toggleClient method is therefore also triggered, which i only want to happen when the user does the onChange.

Is that even possible or should i have another approuch ?

Answer (score 0):

You can either bind the event after changing the value on javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    //... getting obj.params.clientList herre
    var clientStatusList = JSON.parse(obj.params.clientList); 
    for(client in clientStatusList) {
       if(clientStatusList[client].status == true) {
        $("#clientid_" + clientStatusList[client].id).prop('checked', true).change();
       } else {
        $("#clientid_" + clientStatusList[client].id).prop('checked', false).change();
       }
       $("#clientid_" + clientStatusList[client].id).change(function() {
           toggleClient($(this).prop('id'));
       }
    }
});
```

or you can just set a boolean to check if page is loaded

```
var loaded = false;
function toggleClient(id) {
    if (!loaded) return;
    var toggle = $("#clientid_"+id).is(":checked");
    var url = "/toggleClient";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data :{
            "toggle": toggle,
            "id": id,
        }
    });
}
$( document ).ready(function() {  
     loaded = true;
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I probably should have been more clear on the question to start with. I want the event only to fire if the switch is switched by the user and not fire the event if not switched by the user. There is a chance that the switch might change after the page has loaded where the event should also not fire. I'll add this to the main question